# Why is $A - A^T$ unimodular for any Seifert-matrix $A$ of some knot $K$?

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, group-theory, algebraic-topology, knot-theory

I am studying Seifert matrices. Right now I am working with those matrices from a linear algebra perspective, but I will need to understand the knot theory behind it as well. I am using the fact that $A-A^T$ is unimodular for some Seifert-matrix $A$ and I would really appreciate any help on understanding why.

Here is some context:

Let $K$ be some knot in $S^3$, and let $F$ be some Seifert-Surface of $K$. Then as $F$ is orientable we can choose a bicollar $[-1,1]\times F$. The Seifert-Matrix of $K$ according to that Seifert-Surface then is the matrix representing the map
$$f:H_1(F)\times H_1(F)\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$$
given by
$$f([x],[y])=lk(x,y^+)$$
where lk is the linking form and $y^+$ is the pushoff of $y\times\{0\}$ in the bicollar to $y\times\{1\}$. Now one probable needs to write down a basis (classification of surfaces) and do some calculations, but I am unsure on how to see that the generated matrix has the above property in general.

I am new to knot theory, but rather familiar with a lot of basic algebraic topology. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: I have already proven that any two generated Seifert-matrices are S-equivalent. Thus it would suffice to show that one generated matrix has the desired property (maybe one of the non-singular ones of minimal size? But that may be nonsense) and then that the property is preserved under S-equivalency. For congruency it is true obviously. I will look into right/left enlargements resp. reductions later. ( This has to be true , else the statement was false)

Comment: If you consider a standard basis of $H_1(F)$, then $A-A^T$ is just the intersection form which is symplectic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider a genus $g$ oriented surface $S$, with $m$ punctures embedded in $S^3$:
[image]

We have a basis for $H_1(S)$ given by the $g$ blue cycles indicated, the $g$ red cycles and the $m$ green cycles.  The intersection form takes a pair of cycles to the number of intersections, counted with sign coming from the orientation of the ordered directions of the cycles, at the point they cross.

From the diagram we see that with respect to the given basis (red, blue green), the intersection form is represented by $Q$: the diagonal composition of $g$ matrices of the form: $$\left(\begin{array}{cc}0&1\\-1&0\end{array}\right),$$
and $m$ $0$'s.

If we quotient by the null space of the form, then we get a unimodular form $\beta\colon\mathbb{Z}^{2g}\times\mathbb{Z}^{2g}\to\mathbb{Z}$.  That is $\beta$ induces an isomorphism: $$\hat{\beta}\colon \mathbb{Z}^{2g}\stackrel{\tiny\sim}\to {\rm Hom}_\mathbb{Z}(\mathbb{Z}^{2g},\mathbb{Z})$$

A matrix $M$ representing $\beta$ (with respect to some basis) also represents the induced map $\hat{\beta}$ (with respect to the dual basis on ${\rm Hom}_\mathbb{Z}(\mathbb{Z}^{2g},\mathbb{Z}))$.

As $\hat{\beta}$ is an isomorphism, with respect to any basis, the matrix representing $\hat{\beta}$ has determinant $\pm 1$.  Thus $M$ has determinant $\pm1$.

It remains to show that $Q=A-A^T$, where $A$ is the Seifert matrix computed with respect to the red\green\blue basis.  Then they will represent the same form, and we know that any matrix representing this form has determinant $\pm1$.

Let $x_i,y_i$ represent the $i$'th red and blue cycles respectively. Thicken the surface $S$, so that $x_i^+,y_i^+$ are the cycles $x_i,y_i$ pushed to the outer surface of $S$.

Then lk$(y_i,x_i^+)-$lk$(x_i,y_i^+)=1$:

[image]
The cycles here are not linked about the intersection point.

On the other hand:
[image]
The cycles here are linked one degree higher than in the previous diagram, because of the additional link about the intersection point.

If $u,v\in H_1(S)$ do not intersect, then:

$\qquad\qquad\qquad$lk$(u,v^+)=\,$lk$(u,v)=\,$lk$(v,u)=\,$lk$(v,u^+)$.

Thus $A$ is some symmetric matrix plus the diagonal composition of $g$ copies of: $$\left(\begin{array}{cc}0&1\\0&0\end{array}\right),$$
and $m$ $0$'s.

We conclude $Q=A-A^T$ as required.

Comment: Fist of all thank you a lot for the detailed calculations and the pictues! They were really enlightening. One suggestion regarding your assumption:
As mentioned in my qustion it would suffice to show that one geneerated Seifert-matrix has the desired property. While proving that two generated Seifert-matrices are S-equivalent I had to proof that any two Seifert-Surfaces for some given knot are tube-equivalent to one another, furthermore they are tubeequivalent to an arbitrary algoithm surface. Maybe we can find such an algrithm-surface in the desired form?

Comment: tube-equivalent meaning we can transform one into the other by surgeries along arcs.

Comment: I am curious about the following part of your proof:
"It remains to show that $Q=A−A^T$, where $A$ is the Seifert matrix computed with respect to the red\green\blue basis. Then they will represent the same form,..."
Why do A and $A-A^T$ represent the same form? This seems off as $A-A^T$ is always skew-symmetric. If I understood your proof we basically showed the Seifert-Matrix for n times the unknot has the desired property. Can we say something about the intersction form in a more general setting?this could be a way to generalize the statement

Comment: By "they" I meant $Q$ and $A-A^T$.  We know that $Q$, which represents the intersection form, is skew-symmetric and unimodular, regardless of the embedding - it is a purely topological invariant of the surface.

Comment: I just realised how to finish off the argument.  There may be additional terms in $A$, but they will be symmetric, so we still get $Q=A-A^T$.  That seems obvious now.

Comment: Oh yes I was confused sorry. For the symmetry I have to think about it tomorrow again I think. It is kind off too late for me now but it seems correct and I have some symmetry with the linking number in the back off my head. Thank you a lot for the lengthy response and the explanations!

Comment: And maybe it is really too late now, but could you give me an explanation for why the linkingform on (x,y) is the same as on (x,y^+) if x and y do not intersect? Thank you in advance!

Comment: If $x$ and $y$ do not intersect, then they remain some minimal distance apart.  When we thicken $S$, we can just make sure we thicken it by much less than this distance.  Then pushing $y$ to $y^+$ will not make it cross any part of $x$, so the linking number remains the same.

Comment: Thank you very much! Yes, it is obvious now. I really had no thought left yesterday :p

Comment: Sorry for still having my troubles, but how exactly do we know that the green generators can be made to not intersect any other generator? I have drawn some examples and it seems to be true, but I have no agument for why this is the case in general. I feel like I am not seeing the obvious again...

Comment: I guess if we consider a knot we can push the green generato to the boundary of our Seifert-surface and make sure that our red and blue standard generators dont intersect  the boundary? And for a link the boundary components obviously dont intersect?

Comment: Yes.  Essentially if we have a genus $g$ surface with $m$ boundaries, then we can pick our $2g$ $1$-cycles, to avoid small neighbourhoods of the boundaries.  This is effectively the same as avoiding $m$ disks.  If the cycle goes through a disk, then just perturb it a bit to one side.

Comment: Thank you again! Precisely the reason why I love this forum! :)

Comment: One final question to bother you: How do we know $lk(z_i,z_i^+)=0$ in the knotted version?

Comment: As it is a diagonal term in $A$, it will cancel itself out when we take $A-A^T$, so we do not need that result.  The lk$(z_i,z_i^+)$ just provide the last $m$ diagonal entries in the symmetric matrix I refer to in the answer.  I do not think these diagonal entries need be $0$ in general.  Consider a strip with two twists in it.  The two boundary circles are then linked, so bounding a common embedded cylinder (as $z_i$ and $z_i^+$ do) does not guarantee that the linking number is $0$.

Comment: Strictly speaking, my sentence should be bracketed: "symmetric matrix plus (.... and $m$ $0'$'s)".  Was it the non-associtivity here that caused the confusion?

Comment: Thank you! When writing it down I got confused wether I was in A or A-A^T. I had a similar example in mind, where $lk(z_i,z_i)\neq 0$

Comment: After thinking about it for a long time I realized that A does not need to be the diagonal copies of $\begin{pmatrix} 0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$. Take for example the standard Seifert-surface of the trefoil. As our surface is knotted those entries change.

Comment: We have to figure out how this part of $A$ looks in general. The rest of the proof stays the same. Sorry for bothering you again and thanks for any help already!

Comment: Yes $A$ does not look like that, but with respect to the right basis (red/green/blue), $A$ should be something symmetric plus the diagonal copies.  For this proof that is all we need.

Comment: Yes, I finally understood it! This one somehow really troubled me. Thank you for your patience.